# Do we need to explicitly implement ImageCache if we are using ImagePicker library in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am actually trying to implement ImageCache concept when using ImagePicker library, but before implementing this I just want to know if the ImageCache is handled internally by flutter as I've seen logs in my app which says ImageCache.putIfAbsent when I was using NetworkImage.

Please can someone confirm if this is done implicitly or do we need to handle this explicitly.

Many Thanks,
Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There us a default image cache used. You can implement your own to get custom behavior, but you can just rely on the default.

Comment: Thanks very much @Gunter Zochbauer. I will see if i still need to implement imageCache. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, flutter internally manages image cache which is already implemented by `ImageProvider` and its sub classes such as `AssetBundleImageProvider, FileImage, MemoryImage & NetworkImage`.
Flutter caches upto 1000 images(as mentioned in docs).

`ImagePicker` is a plugin that launches a native application to choose an image from. Thus all images show when picking would be handled by the `Gallery` app or what so ever.

So, If you are using `ImagePicker` plugin to pick image and `Image.file` to show images on UI and trying to cache them, then no need of implementing `ImageCache`, because `Image.file` uses `FileImage` which already has image cache implemented.

To read more on `ImageCache`, take look at docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageCache-class.html).

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thank you @Hemanth Raj. I will see if i still need to implement imageCache. Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually used this package `cached_network_image 0.2.1` which internally uses shared preferences instead of reimplementing the image cache, i hope this helps someone who is looking for this kind of functionality.

regards,
Mahi